# Display a ListGrid from the start with all its rows expanded

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I'm using SmartGWT 2.5.

I have a main grid that has its expandable rows in order to display subgrids.
I simply want to display the main grid with all its rows expanded from the start.

I tried to add a listener containing the following code:

```
ListGridRecord[] records = getRecords();
for (ListGridRecord rec : records) {
    expandRecord(rec);
}
```

I tried with DataArrivedHandler and DrawAreaChangedHandler, but I just get javascript errors client-side or only parts of the rows are expanded. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally, I've put a timer of 100 ms within each handler.
The issue was that there was a delay before the full creation of the components (what I want to display is quite complex), and so when the handler was called, not everything was in place yet...

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Grid Grouping, then you can use the following:

```
grid.setGroupStartOpen(GroupStartOpen.ALL);
```

Comment: No, I'm talking about row expansion. Visually, you get an arrow beside each row that enables to open a subelement when clicked upon, following a master-detail pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
listGrid.addDataArrivedHandler(new DataArrivedHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onDataArrived(DataArrivedEvent event) {
            for (ListGridRecord rec : listGrid.getRecords()) {
                listGrid.expandRecord(rec);
            }
        }
    });
```

Should work (worked with previous versions..)
What error do you get?

Comment: I have a main grid who has other grids as expansion components.
When testing the main grid with 2 rows, only the last row get expanded.
When I add the code to the expansion grids, I get this error:

com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
[...]
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): this.body is undefined
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.ja

Comment: For the first point (only the last row expanded) did you  setCanExpandMultipleRecords(Boolean canExpandMultipleRecords) ? for the second point (the error) you can put a breakpoint in Eclipse on the umbrellaException (I don't remember how...) are you sure the expansion grid components are already existing before trying to expand them...

Comment: I didn't set the expandmultiple flag, but it seems to be set by default as users could already expand multiple rows manually. But yes, it seems like the grid itself and its expansion components aren't completely built yet at the time the event get raised. That's why I had to put a timer as a workaround...